# Moving files from local folder to s3 bucket in Go

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to move files under a folder in my local directory to an s3 bucket. I'm aware of the `aws sync s3` command which allows copying local files to an s3 bucket. Is there a way to execute the `aws sync s3` command in a go program? Are there any alternatives, perhaps by using the aws s3 sdk for go?

Comment: I'm not sure about the sync command but you definitely can read the files using `os` and upload them into S3 buckets with the SDK. It's totally doable

Answer (score 2):

AWS doesn't expose any `sync` API with S3. I believe the AWS CLI simply lists all the file in both origin and destination (local folder & S3), computes a difference and uploads/downloads all the elements missing in the destination.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) of the `aws sync s3` also suggests this:

> Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

You will be able to use AWS SDK to list objects in the remote and to upload objects from local to S3, but you will have to manage the local list plus the upload mechanic in your own code.

I don't have first hand experience with AWS SDK for go but a cursory search in the [documentation of the S3 Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/) doesn't yield anything similar to `sync`. I can tell you for sure though that none of the official SDKs for Python nor Javascript exposes any `sync` method.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to upload the files one-at-a-time.

Here is an example from [Performing Basic Amazon S3 Bucket Operations - AWS SDK for Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-basic-bucket-operations.html):

```golang
/*
   Copyright 2010-2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

   This file is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
   You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of
   the License is located at

    http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/

   This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
*/

package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

// Creates a S3 Bucket in the region configured in the shared config
// or AWS_REGION environment variable.
//
// Usage:
//    go run s3_upload_object.go BUCKET_NAME FILENAME
func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 3 {
        exitErrorf("bucket and file name required\nUsage: %s bucket_name filename",
            os.Args[0])
    }

    bucket := os.Args[1]
    filename := os.Args[2]

    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to open file %q, %v", err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    // Initialize a session in us-west-2 that the SDK will use to load
    // credentials from the shared credentials file ~/.aws/credentials.
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-west-2")},
    )

    // Setup the S3 Upload Manager. Also see the SDK doc for the Upload Manager
    // for more information on configuring part size, and concurrency.
    //
    // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#NewUploader
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    // Upload the file's body to S3 bucket as an object with the key being the
    // same as the filename.
    _, err = uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),

        // Can also use the `filepath` standard library package to modify the
        // filename as need for an S3 object key. Such as turning absolute path
        // to a relative path.
        Key: aws.String(filename),

        // The file to be uploaded. io.ReadSeeker is preferred as the Uploader
        // will be able to optimize memory when uploading large content. io.Reader
        // is supported, but will require buffering of the reader's bytes for
        // each part.
        Body: file,
    })
    if err != nil {
        // Print the error and exit.
        exitErrorf("Unable to upload %q to %q, %v", filename, bucket, err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Successfully uploaded %q to %q\n", filename, bucket)
}

func exitErrorf(msg string, args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, msg+"\n", args...)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```